# Main thread not exiting when manually loading assemblies

Tags: c#, .net

We are loading assemblies via `AppDomain.AssemblyResolve` event. This has been working without problems for years.

Since recently our App doesn't exit after closing the UI.

The problem has to do with custom assembly loading and may be reproduced with a simple commandline application consisting of two projects (assemblies):

- ProcessTest - the main assembly, producing a commmandline exe
- MyLibrary - a library project with a static class with 1 method (`HelperClasse.DoSomething`)

The main project references the `MyLibrary` project, and the reference has its `Copy Local` property set to `False`, so that the assembly dll is not copied to the execution folder but instead loaded via AssemblyResolve.

The code of the main project looks as follows:

```cs
using MyLibrary;
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Reflection;

namespace ProcessTest
{
    static Program()
    {
        AppDomain.CurrentDomain.AssemblyResolve += ResolveAssembly;
    }

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Begin");

        // call method in other assembly "MyAssembly"
        HelperClass.DoSomething();

        Console.WriteLine("End");
    }


    private static Assembly ResolveAssembly(object sender, ResolveEventArgs args)
    {
        // we only handle resolves of MyLibrary.dll
        if (!args.Name.Contains("MyLibrary"))
            return null;

        // load the assembly manually from its own project folder
#if DEBUG
        var filename = @"..\..\..\MyLibrary\bin\Debug\MyLibrary.dll";
#else
        var filename = @"..\..\..\MyLibrary\bin\Release\MyLibrary.dll";
#endif
           
        using (FileStream fs = new FileStream(fileName, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.Read))
        {
            var block = new byte[fs.Length];
            fs.Read(block, 0, block.Length);
            var assembly = Assembly.Load(block);
            return assembly;
        }
    }
}
```

The `HelperClass` in the `MyLibrary` project looks like this:

```cs
using System;

namespace MyLibrary
{
    public class HelperClass
    {
        public static void DoSomething()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Method in HelperClass");
        }
    }
}
```

I would expect the app to run, print its output and then exit.
In most cases it doesn't exit though.

- When the referenced assembly is copied to the execution folder, the app exits normally. The assembly is then loaded by the default mechanism and not via `AssemblyResolve`.
- Under some circumstances the app exits normally, e.g. when running it inside Windows Sandbox

The App is targeting .NET Framework 4.8.

We have been using the `AssemblyResolve` pattern for years and the apps always exited normally. Its only since recently that we are experiencing this "not exiting" behavior.

There must have been some change in windows or .NET Framework that caused this change in behavior.

Any hints or help would be appreciated.

Comment: please provide minimal example .. because the only problem(and unknown) here is `HelperClass.DoSomething();`

Comment: Check that you do not have any background thread keeping the application alive.

Comment: HelperClass.DoSomething() is not the problem. The only thing it does is `Console.WriteLine()`

Comment: There is no other thread running, only the main thread.

Answer (score 0):

We found the reason for the problem.

It turned out that it had to do with the virus scanner that was installed on the affected systems.